# private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding Not Working?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.bottom_nav_control)
        setupWithNavController(binding.bottomNavigationView, navController)
    } 
}
```

Here,private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding not working?!
i tried adding

build Features {view Binding true}

these code to enable binding on my build.but it didn't work

if you know any other answer comment here

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: it shows this error -> Unresolved reference: ActivityMainBinding

Comment: Have you treid to `invalidate cache`?

Comment: i tried to clean project and rebuild project but it also didn't work

Comment: drop me your AnyDesk.

Comment: Do you actually have an `activity_main.xml`? The Binding is always named after the activity xml files. if you have a `activity_blabla.xml` it will be `ActivityBlablaBinding`

Comment: yes i have activity_main.xml,which is renamed as mainactivity.xml

Comment: @Fiaz that's the problem. It will be `MainactivityBinding` then

Answer (score 1):

Refer to your comment, since you renamed your `xml` to `mainactivity.xml`. You can call it by using

```
MainactivityBinding
```

instead

```
ActivityMainBinding
```

Comment: Actually `MainactivityBinding`. Because of no underscore. `main_activity.xml` would be `MainActivityBinding`

Comment: But that also didn't work?! it shows -> Unresolved reference: MainactivityBinding

Comment: @Fiaz small `a` like `MainactivityBinding`

Answer (score 0):

Remove these line and add below one for activity

```
 binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
 setContentView(binding.root)

 private lateinit var binding :  ActivityMainBinding
 binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.your_layout)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was necessary to import this:

```java
import com.example.yourproject.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
```